# Display the value from database to input

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What I need here is to display the maincode value on textbox depending on the value of select category.

If I choose House , the textbox value should be ACR100.

The table structure is shown below:

**Database Table**

```
id  |  maincode | category  
1   |  ACR100   |  House
2   |  ACR200   |  Park  
3   |  ACR300   |  Field
```

**Code**

```
<select name="category" id="category" onchange="GetChangedValue(this.value);">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");

$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY maincode");
while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc())
{
echo "<option value=\"".$row['category']."\">".$row['category']."</option>\r";
}                               
?>
</select>

--empty--
<input>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: make an ajax call on select event

Comment: what you want to do , please give your question clearly

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh I want to display the value from database depending on what I choose in dropdown.

Comment: you wan to display value from dropdown when it is changed ? am i right , if yes where you want to display the value

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh not the value of dropdown. Display the value depending on the value of dropdown. For example If I choose House, the value on textbox should be ACR100. Display the maincode not the category field in database.

Answer (score 2):

### [- See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/L3wCz/)

You want something like this? From your question I can't clearly figure out what you want.

I have used static values here, you can use values from DB there with a simple JS function:

```
function GetChangedValue(value1)
{
  document.getElementById("inp").value=value1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `onchange` event to fill textbox value

```
 <select name="category" id="category" onchange="GetChangedValue(this.value);">
    <option value="house new-ACR100">house new</option>
    <option value="park new-ACR200">park new</option>
    <option value="field new-ACR300">field new</option>
</select>


    <input type="textbox" id="filler" />
    <script>
    function GetChangedValue(category) {
        var code=category.split('-');
        document.getElementById("filler").value = code[1];

    }
    </script>
```

like wise you explode in php and use for your query

demo here http://jsfiddle.net/43xVd/1/

Comment: the option value should be remain category. Because I used that in my query. Like in table structure, Category = House and maincode = ACR100.

Comment: I encounter a problem. If my category has a space?

Comment: updated the code , there is no problem after introducing space